# PDO Update with PHP and Arrays

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I have an update statement that should update prices for items in a database, as the number of items can vary, I have tried using an array and then looping through the array. I have double checked all my inputs twice but cannot seem to nail down the problem, basically nothing is updating!

Here is what I am sending in my POST request to the form processor

```
itemid[]    8
itemid[]    3
itemid[]    12
itemid[]    4
itemid[]    13
itemid[]    5
itemid[]    10
itemid[]    6
itemid[]    9
itemid[]    7
itemid[]    2
itemid[]    15
itemid[]    11
itemid[]    14
itemid[]    1
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 1
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
price[] 0.0
shopid  3
tag prices
```

and my processing code

```
else if($tag == 'prices')
{
    $shopid = $_POST['shopid'];
    $itemid = $_POST['itemid'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];


    foreach($itemid as $key => $n)
    {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=servershop', '$user', '$pass');
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE prices SET price = ? WHERE item_id = ? and shop_id = ?");
        $stmt->bindValue(1, $price[$key]);
        $stmt->bindValue(2, $n);
        $stmt->bindValue(3, $shopid);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

and finally my table that should be updating:

```
shop_id(int),item_id(int),price(double)
3,1,0
3,2,0
3,3,0
3,4,0
3,5,0
3,6,0
3,7,0
3,8,0
3,9,0
3,10,0
3,11,0
3,12,0
3,13,0
3,14,0
3,15,0
```

I have both PHP Errors and $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); enabled, however no error is shown in the firebug console.

Can anyone spot where I have made a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Why do you expect PHP errors to show up in the Firebug console? Try debugging the code to see which part is actually executed with which variable values. If you do not have a step-by-step debugger at hand, use `var_dump` statements in the code.

Comment: You know what, I have no idea! I was thinking that I would see the error in the response for some reason, however I have no response as something is going wrong, I am downloading PHPStorm as I write this, even var_dump is not displaying anything, maybe as I am calling this as an ajax request?? Anyway I will see if I can work it out in PHPstorm

Comment: OK, for an AJAX request, you should have a look at the response in the Firebug console. But if it is empty, you probably still have some PHP settings that prevent displaying errors (i.e. `display_errors`, `display_startup_errors`, `error_reporting`)

Comment: just error_reporting(E_ALL);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting that I can't post a comment.  I don't know what version of PHP you're using, but one thing I noticed was:

```
'$user', '$pass'
```

If this is the actual code then perhaps these variables are not being interpolated.  Values inside single quotes are generally not expanded from my understanding.  It could be your connection to the database is failing there (e.g. trying to use literals '$user' and '$pass' to connect).

Also, you really only need to prepare the statement once and rebind your parameters in the loop.

Comment: Hi Kris, these are not the actual code, just added this to hide my testing username password which are hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

You're submitting the itemid as keys for the prices which is fine, but you're not associating those keys with the prices. Either you iterate the item id's then use current() and next() on the prices array, or you fill the prices array with the keys from itemid.

```
$new_array = array_fill_keys($itemid,$price);

foreach($new_array as $key => $n)
    ....
}
```